# Logical error in filling QTableWidget and filling all of nodes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

i have the following code `(PyQt)`:

```
searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setRowCount(rowCounter)
searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)

for row in range(rowCounter):
    for column in range(5):
        for result in query:

            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_fromUtf8(result.name))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,column,item)

            #item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(String(result.bought_price))
            #item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            #searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,column+1,item)

            #item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(result.bought_date)
            #item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            #searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,column+2,item)

            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(result.stock)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,column+3,item)

            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(result.minimum_bound)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,column+4,item)
```

When i search in DB, i `print result.name` or `print result.stock` , everything is OK. But when i import them into `QtableWidget` i see just node `result.name` addeed to `widgets`. (all of nodes filled  from `result.name`)

**My Question** is , How i fill rows and columns with my fields?

Comment: try commenting out the line `for column in range(5):`

Comment: Thank you...! i comment out and solved..., Of course i should column by hand: 0, 1 , 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out the line `for column in range(5):` and set `column` to `0`.

There seems to be no point in running that loop because you are manually incrementing the column number in which you want `item` to be added.

One more thing there is no point in running a loop over `query` because what appears in a particular row is what comes out last in `query`. Plus you are uselessly choking the memory by creating `(len(query) - 1) * 5` items which could potentially be never used again. Better comment out `for result in query:` and replace it with `result = list(query)[-1]`.

Comment: I solved , it were very important : 1. column for 2. because i defined my locale persian Iran, it couldn't get integer, So i defined a function for convert integer to persian.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh not sure I quite get what you are pointing out to